# How safe are extensions in Visual Studio code?

Tags: security, visual-studio-code, malware-detection

How safe are extensions in visual Studio code?

Can extensions introduce malware?

Is safe to install any extension?

Answer (score 20):

They can contain malware, yes. When you download and run an extension, you are trusting it to do pretty much anything it wants with the permissions of your user.

VS Code does not implement sandboxing (like browsers do), and the code is not much restricted.

Having said that, a malicious extension would likely be uncovered pretty quickly. As these files are signed, a third party attacker has no easy way to modify an existing one, or somehow release a fake one, they would have to compromise the real developer first. Also many of them are open source (which btw is no guarantee the released version is built from the public source, but again, it is easy to check as extensions are just zip files).

So in short: extensions can in theory be malicious, but especially in case of well-known extensions, the likelihood of you getting a malicious version before others discover it and it gets removed is probably very low. On the other hand, extensions used by many people can be a nice target for sophisticated attackers, because security controls might sometimes be a lot more lenient than at the companies where those extensions are used.

TL;DR: only you can tell whether you want to accept the risk, which is not very high, but also not negligible, especially with smaller, niche extensions that get less thorough review by the community.

Comment: May I ask for a citation regarding "As these files are signed..."? [This issue](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-vsce/issues/191) indicates that the Visual Studio Code Extension Manager does not support signing extensions.

Answer (score 3):

According to Microsoft:

> The Marketplace runs a virus scan on each extension package that's published to ensure its safety. The virus scan is run for each new extension and for each extension update. Until the scan is all clear, the extension won't be published in the Marketplace for public usage.

https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/extension-marketplace#_can-i-trust-extensions-from-the-marketplace

However, a successful virus scan does not guarantee there are no security vulnerabilities in the code (whether ignorant or malicious); it just verifies that no known viruses were found. Also, it is possible to quite closely impersonate a legitimate extension, as shown in the research in this article: [https://blog.aquasec.com/can-you-trust-your-vscode-extensions#:~:text=The%20Dangers%20of%20VSCode%20Extensions&text=Some%20merely%20change%20the%20theme,ransomwares%2C%20wipers%2C%20and%20more](https://blog.aquasec.com/can-you-trust-your-vscode-extensions#:%7E:text=The%20Dangers%20of%20VSCode%20Extensions&text=Some%20merely%20change%20the%20theme,ransomwares%2C%20wipers%2C%20and%20more).

In short, it is your responsibility to make sure that you carefully review any extension before installing it. Personally, I like to look at the number of downloads as well as the creator before downloading any extension. A high number of downloads as well as a reliable author (such as microsoft.com) are good indicators that an extension is safe.

P.S.: the blue verified checkmark next to an extension does not mean that the extension is verified; it only verifies that the publisher owns a specific domain--which could be any domain (see the aquasec article above).

Comment: I'm fine with Microsoft not giving any guarantees on the security of extensions. 
However, I don't understand how I should review extensions that don't have their source code public.

Answer (score 1):

There are (at least) two ways that bad software can do bad-stuff™ to you / your machine through extensions:

#### Non-malicious extension, malicious workspace

A non-malicious extension can be taken advantage of / used as an attack vector by a malicious workspace. To an extent, VS Code's builtin workspace trust mechanism can protect you from this. You can read about this in more detail in https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/workspace-trust#_extensions. The gist is that when you open a workspace for the first time, VS Code will ask you whether you want to trust that workspace. If you say no, VS Code will open the workspace in "restricted mode", where extensions that do not explicitly opt in to being runnable in that mode will be disabled. Extensions can also configure themselves to be forcibly disabled in restricted mode, or only have limited functionality in restricted mode (Note that the user can also manually override what the extension chooses (see the `extensions.supportUntrustedWorkspaces` setting)).

All this depends upon said extension being non-malicious.

#### Malicious extension

Yes, extensions can be malicious. In the same workspace trust doc, it also states:

> Note: Workspace Trust can not prevent a malicious extension from executing code and ignoring Restricted Mode. You should only install and run extensions that come from a well-known publisher that you trust.

To be fair, the same kind of general wisdom goes for any kind of program you install on your machine and which doesn't run inside some sort of sandbox, such as a browser (which is a good time to point out that if you're accessing/using VS Code in a browser, such as on a site like github.dev, then the browser's sandbox is there to act as a layer of protection for the rest of your machine from whatever malicious program might be running as part of a page).

VS Code itself *does* have a sandbox (the Electron Sandbox), which you can read about in https://code.visualstudio.com/blogs/2022/11/28/vscode-sandbox,

> For a long time, Electron has allowed direct use of Node.js APIs in HTML and JavaScript. [...] Enabling sandbox mode for the renderer process reduces its capabilities for improved security and to align more with the web model: while HTML and JavaScript are still allowed, usage of Node.js is not. Components in the renderer process that require access to system resources will have to delegate to another process that is not sandboxed.

The use of the Electron Sandbox was rolled out in version 1.79, which you can read about in https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_79#_electron-sandbox-enabled-for-all-users. However, the extension host is not inside that sandbox. **However**, NodeJS is intentionally [still fully supported within the extension host](https://code.visualstudio.com/blogs/2022/11/28/vscode-sandbox#_a-new-electron-api-utilityprocess), which is not part of the renderer process.

#### What to do if you have reason to think that an extension in the marketplace is malicious

Go to the extension's marketplace and click the "Report Abuse" button in the sidebar and go through the abuse-reporting process.

Answer (score -7):

This is not really right, I know that if you download from a safe website also known as microsoft.com, you are pretty much safe unless a hacker is already on your computer, so it can compromise your sites and make the downloads malicious. I know this because I have downloaded many things but never got an alert or ransomware. So, you are basically safe unless a hacker, etc. is already on your computer. So live safe guys!

Comment: There's so many technical inaccuracies in this answer, I'm not even quite sure where to begin. Pretty much every sentence in this post is tainted with dangerous and unsubstantiated conjecture.

Comment: "I know that you cannot get food poisoning from KFC because I have eaten at KFC many times and never thrown up right afterwards."